# What type should I set to component prop of Vuelidate field?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuelidate

Look, I have a view where I need to validate some fields. The main problem is that I want to pass prop to a **InputValidationWrapper Component** like `v$.[keyField]`. But I don't know what type to set.

SignInView.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="sign-in-view">
        <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit" class="sign-in-form">
            <div class="inputs-container">
                <InputValidationWrapper :validationField="v$.email" required email>
                    <BaseInput title="Email" v-model="formData.email" />
                </InputValidationWrapper>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import BaseInput from "@/components/inputs/BaseInput.vue";
import InputValidationWrapper from "@/components/validators/InputValidationWrapper.vue";

import useVuelidate from "@vuelidate/core";
import { required, email } from "@vuelidate/validators";
import { computed, reactive } from "vue";

const formData = reactive({
    email: "",
    password: "",
});

const validationRules = computed(() => {
    return {
        email: { required, email },
        password: { required },
    };
});
const v$ = useVuelidate(validationRules, formData);

const onSubmit = async () => {
    const result = await v$.value.$validate();
    if (!result) return;
    console.log("submit");
};
</script>
```

InputValidationWrapper.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="input-wrapper">
        <slot />
        <div class="errors-block">
            <RequiredValidation
                :isDirty="validationField.$dirty"
                :isInvalid="validationField.required.$invalid"
                v-if="required" />
            <EmailValidation :isDirty="validationField.$dirty" :isInvalid="validationField.email.$invalid" v-if="email" />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import RequiredValidation from "./RequiredValidation.vue";
import EmailValidation from "./EmailValidation.vue";
import type { NestedValidations } from "@vuelidate/core/index.js";

type PropsType = {
    validationField: NestedValidations; //???
    required?: boolean;
    email?: boolean;
};

defineProps<PropsType>();
</script>
```

As you can see I make new component for each error and pass a props there as simple boolean. But `validationField.$dirty` throws an error `Property '$dirty' does not exist on type NestedValidations<ValidationArgs<unknown>, unknown>'.` and the same thing with `validationField.email.$invalid`

Comment: If you expect validation object inside of the comp then you shouldn't pass a single rule, should be `:v$="v$"`

Comment: I except the validation rule but of one exact field. And I don't know what type should it be. NestedValidator doesn't work.

Comment: But you use it like validationField.email.$invalid, which is not correct. Otherwise it's possibly RuleResult

Comment: Look, here validation field is ```v$.email```, and ```validationField.email``` is rule that I want to check, if field is email. It's the same as ```validationField.required```.

Comment: validationField isn't expected to have email or required IIRC. You can debug v$.email structure to check what nested props are actually there.

Comment: Yes, I know and I was asking what type should I use because nestedValidator type doesn't give me default functions for field validation like $dirty, etc. I think that it's should be combination of few types with opitonal validation options like email, required. Validator prop type doesn't allow me to pass ```v$.email```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own interface to pass the Vuelidate Validation:

i.e.

```js
export interface VuelidateValidation {
  $errors: ErrorObject[];
  $error: boolean;
  $invalid: boolean;
  $dirty: boolean;
  $touch: () => void;
}
```

And then you just use that in your component:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
export interface Props {
  validation?: VuelidateValidation
}
const props = defineProps<Props>();
const model = defineModel();
</script>
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="model" @input="validation?.$touch" @blur="validation?.$touch" />
  <div v-if="validation?.$error">
    Something wrong here.
  </div>
</template>
```

When you use that component you can just pass your vuelidate validation property:

```
<template>
  <MyComponent :validation="v$.email" />
</template>
```